# Given an array of integers, needing run operations on a Max_Heap. Getting error "segmentation fault", Any ideas? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, swap, max-heap

This is one of my first posts on here so please bear with me.
I am working on an assignment and have looked at various sources to create and solve this problem.

[Prompt for problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5yLE.png)
I have written the max_heapify, print, build_heap, and delete_root function but the only thing I am getting on output is *exited, segmentation fault* I have ran similar code through the same compiler and not had any issue.

I realize my code is not perfectly indented but if anyone has any suggestions on how to make this run it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


void max_heapify(int arr[], int n, int i){

   int max_val = i;
   int left = 2*i +1;
   int right = 2*i +2;

      // if left child is larger than root 
      // set  root equal to left child
 if ( left < n && arr[left] > arr[max_val] )
     max_val = left;

     // if right child is larger than largest 
 if (right < n && arr[right] > max_val)
     max_val = right;

    // if largest is not root
 if (max_val != i)
 {
          //swap values
      int temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[max_val];
      arr[max_val] = temp;

      max_heapify(arr,n,i);

}

}

  void buildh(int arr[],int n)
  {
     //index of last non leaf node
    int indx = (n/2) -1;

    for (int i = indx; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      max_heapify(arr,n,i);
    }
   }

 void printh(int arr[], int n) 
    { 
      cout << "Heap is:\n"; 

       for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
            cout << arr[i] << " "; 
            cout << "\n"; 
    } 

  void delete_root(int arr[], int n)
  {
  int last = arr[n-1];
  arr[0] = last;
  n = n-1;
  max_heapify(arr,n,0);
  }


    int main() {

     int arr[] = {28,12,17,5,7,22,13,12,4,11,16}; // create an array of values
     int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 

     buildh(arr,n);

     printh(arr,n);

     delete_root(arr,n);

     return 0;


     }
```

Comment: First off, using #include <bits/stdc++.h> is a bad habit. If you are going to use it, though, then you don't need to add any other #include statements. In other words, you can get rid of #include <iostream> and #include <math.h> in your program.

Comment: I get a stack overflow after `max_heapify` calls itself recursively 3802 times.

Comment: Please see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Now is a good time to learn how to debug your own code.

Comment: Whene your code return from `max_heapify`

Answer (score 1):

The segfault occurring due to `max_heapify()` keep on calling itself recursively and not hitting the terminating condition.

Two problems in your code:

**Problem 1:**

In `max_heapify()`, in this statement

```
 if (right < n && arr[right] > max_val)
```

it should be `arr[max_val]`. Correct statement will be

```
 if (right < n && arr[right] > arr[max_val])
```

**Problem 2:**

In every call to `max_heapify()` you are heapifying element at `i`<sup>th</sup> location

```
      max_heapify(arr,n,i);
                        ^^
```

Instead, you should pass the index `max_val` once it identified the maximum between `left` and `right` child and swapped the `a[i]` and `a[max_val]` values

```
      max_heapify(arr,n,max_val);
```

With this the recursive call will heapify the array element at `max_val` location.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue occurs in this function:

```
void max_heapify(int arr[], int n, int i){
    int max_val = i;
    int left = 2*i +1;
    int right = 2*i +2;

    // if left child is larger than root, set root equal to left child
    if ( left < n && arr[left] > arr[max_val] )
        max_val = left;

    // if right child is larger than largest 
    if (right < n && arr[right] > max_val)
        max_val = right;

    // if largest is not root
    if (max_val != i){
        //swap values
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[max_val];
        arr[max_val] = temp;

        max_heapify(arr,n,i);
    }
}
```

At the very end, you call `max_heapify()` within itself. The problem with this code is that there is no terminating condition for the recursion; in other words, there is nothing to stop it from recursing on to infinity. As @Retired Ninja commented, this procedure is likely to be the cause of the `Segmentation Fault` because it exceeds the maximum allowed recursion depth.

To fix this, you need to think about ways to reduce the recursion depth of `max_heapify()` (Do you really need to call it recursively?).

Comment: `max_val == i` is the terminating condition for the recursion.